# How to exclude or skip the sender when broadcasting a message to multiple clients (multithreaded java socket)

Tags: java, multithreading, sockets

Suppose I have the following method:

```
static synchronized void broadcast(String message, String name) throws IOException
{ 
        // Sends the message to every client including the sender. 
        Socket s; 
        PrintWriter p; 
        for (int i = 0; i < clientList.size(); i++)
        { 
            s = clientList.get(i); 
            p = new PrintWriter(s.getOutputStream(), true); 
            p.println(name+": "+message); 
        } 
}
```

**Notice:** the line that says `// Sends the message to every client including the sender`

**Goal:** Change the method so that it will: `//Sends the message to every client EXCEPT the sender`

What changes could I make to the code above so that the broadcast method sends the message to every client **EXCLUDING** the sender?

The line that's causing it to be sent to all clients is the `for` loop combined with the line that says `p.println(name+": "+message);`

Some people have suggested using a `hashmap` as in:

`Map<Integer, java.net.Socket> clients = new HashMap<Integer, java.net.Socket> ();` 
but how would I use that hashmap in a for loop to broadcast to every client except the sender?
Can someone provide an example where hashmaps are used to **exclude**
clients from a message being broadcasted to them? Currently I have a variable called `clientList`, should I replace this with the hashmap?

Full context of code:

```
import java.io.*; 
import java.net.*; 
import java.util.*;
public class ChatServer
{ 

        /* 
         * Sets up a server for multiple conversations. 
         * 
         * Join in by typing  
         * telnet x y 
         * where x and y are the computer's name and port as 
         * given when the Chatter starts. 
         * 
         */ 

        private static LinkedList<Socket> clientList = new LinkedList<Socket>(); 

        public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException
        { 
            // Get the port and create a socket there. 
            int port = 8190; 
            ServerSocket listener = new ServerSocket(port); 
            System.out.println("The Chat Server is running on port "+port); 

            // Listen for clients. Start a new handler for each. 
            // Add each client to the list. 
            while (true) 
            { 
                Socket client = listener.accept(); 
                new ChatHandler(client).start(); 
                System.out.println("New client on client's port "+ client.getPort()); 
                clientList.add(client); 
            }   
        } 

        static synchronized void broadcast(String message, String name) throws IOException
        { 
            // Sends the message to every client including the sender. 
            Socket s; 
            PrintWriter p; 
            for (int i = 0; i < clientList.size(); i++)
            { 
                s = clientList.get(i); 
                p = new PrintWriter(s.getOutputStream(), true); 
                p.println(name+": "+message); 
            } 
        } 
        static synchronized void remove(Socket s)
        { 
            clientList.remove(s); 
        }     
} 

    class ChatHandler extends Thread 
    { 

        /* The Chat Handler class is called from the Chat Server: 
         * one thread for each client coming in to chat. 
         */ 

        private BufferedReader in; 
        private PrintWriter out; 
        private Socket toClient; 
        private String name; 

        ChatHandler(Socket s)
        { 
            toClient = s; 
        } 

        public void run()
        { 
            try 
            { 
                /* Create i-o streams through the socket we were given
                 * when the thread was instantiated and welcome the new client. 
                 */ 

                in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(toClient.getInputStream())); 
                out = new PrintWriter(toClient.getOutputStream(), true); 
                out.println("*** Welcome to the Chatter ***"); 
                out.println("Type BYE to end"); 
                out.print("What is your name? ");  
                out.flush(); 
                String name = in.readLine(); 
                ChatServer.broadcast(name+" has joined the discussion.", "Chatter"); 

                // Read lines and send them off for broadcasting. 
                while (true)
                { 
                    String s = in.readLine();
                    if (s.startsWith("BYE"))
                    {
                        ChatServer.broadcast(name+" has left the discussion.", "Chatter"); 
                        break; 
                    } 
                    ChatServer.broadcast(s, name); 
                } 
                ChatServer.remove(toClient); 
                toClient.close(); 
            } 
            catch (Exception e) 
            { 
                System.out.println("Chatter error: "+e); 
            } 
        } 
    }
```

Comment: Add UTF-8 (`StandardCharsets.UTF_8`) to both `InputStreamReader` and `PrintWriter` so Greek, emojis and so on can be communicated on different computers. Otherwise every computer uses its default encoding.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
static synchronized void broadcast(Socket sender, String message, String name) throws IOException { //Add the sender socket here.
        // Sends the message to every client including the sender. 
        Socket s; 
        PrintWriter p; 
        for (int i = 0; i < clientList.size(); i++)
        { 
            s = clientList.get(i);
            if(s != sender) { //If the client is not equal to sender.
                p = new PrintWriter(s.getOutputStream(), true); 
                p.println(name+": "+message);
            } 
        } 
}
```

Call the method like this

```
ChatServer.broadcast(toClient, s, name); //The toClient variable is inside your chathandler which is the reference to the socket which is the sender.
```